# Setting Random_Seed LDA Mallet Implementation (For replicability of results)

Tags: python, lda, topic-modeling

May I know which version of the LDA Mallet Wrapper has the random_seed parameter included in the code? I tried version Mallet 2.0.8, but I am getting TypeError unexpected keyword argument. Or should I be downloading the ldamallet.py from github then replacing the "mallet" script in the bin folder? Thanks.

TypeError: init() got an unexpected keyword argument 'random_seed'

Update: In order for the random_seed parameter to work, download the ldamallet.py file from Github and paste it into the Python>Gensim>Model directory. No changes are required for the mallet-2.0.8 wrapper.

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow, can you share the snippet of code that is not working please? If you are talking about this library https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/wrappers/ldamallet.html I see `random_seed` as last parameter.

Comment: Thanks Danilo! In theory, based on radimrehurek's post, it should work. But if I am not wrong random_seed was not present in the original LDA Mallet wrapper. It was included later on [https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/pull/2153 ]
`ldamallet = gensim.models.wrappers.LdaMallet(mallet_path, corpus=corpus, num_topics=20, id2word=dictionary, topic_threshold=0.0, iterations=100, random_seed=0)`

Comment: Looking at the [commit history](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/commits/develop?after=b86807382dd366f1a4dd80baee7d1c5101bf29b1+34) the first version published after `random_seed` was merged is 3.7.0

Comment: @DaniloCabello thanks for your patience. It works now. I finally figured out that I had to download the ldamallet.py [https://github.com/rsdel2007/gensim/commit/da7c553d29c9b7f5685bcfb8c7f46d5d54c9d46f] file from Github and paste in the python2.7>gensim>model folder.